# Change date format of pdf file in a folder

Tags: python, operating-system, datetime-format

A zip folder has few pdf files and their names are in the format `October 1, 1970.pdf`, `March 27, 1995.pdf` etc
I want to change the format of each file to `YYYY-MM-DD` in python

```
import datetime

date1 = "/Users/akshitarora/Downloads/Akshitpythoncole/"

datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%m-%d-%Y")

print(datetime.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '/Users/akshitarora/Downloads/Akshitpythoncole/' 
            does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'
```

Comment: edit question, select code and use button `{}` (on toolbar) to correctly display code in question.

Comment: read error message again. It explains you that folder name `"/Users/akshitarora/Downloads/Akshitpythoncole/"` is not in format `"%m-%d-%Y"`. You have to get filenames from folder and use them with `strptime`. It will not get names from file automatically. Use `list_with_filenames = os.listdir(folder_name)`

Comment: it is not good idea to use variable name `datetime` if you use module with name `datetime`. This way you overwrite this name and when you will try to use some function from module `datetime` in some other line then it will get value from variable `datetime` instead of module `datetime`

Comment: date `October 1, 1970` doesn't fit to format `%m-%d-%Y` but to `%B %d, %Y`. And don't forget to remove file extension when you will do `strptime(filename_without_extension, "%B %d, %Y")` or use ` "%B %d, %Y.pdf"` as format.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes.

First: you have folder name but it will not get filenames from folder. You have to use `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob(...)` to get it.

```
import os

folder = "/Users/akshitarora/Downloads/Akshitpythoncole/"
filenames = os.listdir(folder)
```

And next you have to use loop to change every filename separatelly.

Second: date `October 1, 1970` doesn't fit to format `%m-%d-%Y` but to `%B %d, %Y`.

And when you will use `strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y")` don't forget to remove file extension. OR use extension in format `"%B %d, %Y.pdf"`. You can also use extension when you format new name `"%m-%d-%Y.pdf"`

---

When you will change names - `using os.rename()` - you have to remember that you have to add folder to filename to create full path -  `os.path.join(folder, filename)`

I didn't test it (because I don't have this folder and these files) but it should work

```
import os
import datetime

folder = "/Users/akshitarora/Downloads/Akshitpythoncole/"

filenames = os.listdir(folder)
#filenames = ['October 1, 1970.pdf', 'March 27, 1995.pdf']

for name in filenames:

    if name.endswith('.pdf'):
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y.pdf")
        new_name = dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y.pdf")
        print(new_name)

        old_path = os.path.join(folder, name)
        new_path = os.path.join(folder, new_name)
```

---

BTW: It is not good idea to use variable with name `datetime` because you use module with the same name `datetime` and using variable with this name you don't have access to module.

---

**EDIT:** Problem with names 'October 1, 1972 A.pdf', 'October 1, 1972 B.pdf'

I check if name has 3 spaces and then split it on last space to get list with parts 
`['October 1, 1972', 'A.pdf']`. Now I can convert date in first part and later join it with second part to create name `10-01-1972 A.pdf`

```
import datetime

filenames = ['October 1, 1972 A.pdf', 'October 1, 1972 B.pdf', 'October 1, 1972.pdf']

for name in filenames:
    if name.endswith('.pdf'):
        if name.count(' ') == 3:
            parts = name.rsplit(' ', 1) # split on last space
            print(' parts:', parts) 
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(parts[0], "%B %d, %Y")
            parts[0] = dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
            new_name = ' '.join(parts)
        else:
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y.pdf")
            new_name = dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y.pdf")

        print(name, '->', new_name)
```

Comment: Hi, There are 600 files and I cannot write each name, I need something to automate it. Also if there are two files of the same name then they are marked as October 1, 1972 A and October 1, 1972 B

Comment: man, you have `os.listdir()` in code to get all filenames from folder. Did you ever run this code ?

Comment: as for problem `October 1, 1972 A.pdf` and `October 1, 1972 B.pdf` - you can check if name has 3 spaces and split it on last space to create pair `"October 1, 1972"` and `"A.pdf"` and then you can convert date to new format and later you can add `"A.pdf"` to new date. - `"October 1, 1972 A.pdf".count(' ') == 3`

Comment: I added code which works with names like `October 1, 1972 A.pdf` and it still works with names lik `October 1, 1972.pdf`. Next time you should add this example at start in question. If you have more complex names (ie. with more spaces) then you may need more complex method.

Answer (score 0):

import os
import datetime

filenames = os.listdir(folder)

for name in filenames:

```
if name.endswith('A.pdf'):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y A.pdf")
    new_name = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.pdf")
    print(new_name)
if name.endswith('B.pdf'):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y B.pdf")
    new_name = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.pdf")
    print(new_name)
if name.endswith('C.pdf'):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y C.pdf")
    new_name = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.pdf")
    print(new_name)
if name.endswith('D.pdf'):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y D.pdf")
    new_name = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.pdf")
    print(new_name)
if name.endswith('E.pdf'):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y E.pdf")
    new_name = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.pdf")
    print(new_name)
if name.endswith('F.pdf'):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y F.pdf")
    new_name = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.pdf")
    print(new_name)
if name.endswith('G.pdf'):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(name, "%B %d, %Y G.pdf")
    new_name = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.pdf")
    print(new_name)


    old_path = os.path.join(folder, name)
    new_path = os.path.join(folder, newName)
```